# Maximum number of classes YOLO net can recognize on mobile

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, inference

I'm trying to make a mobile app on image recognition(Computer Vision Application) . Does anyone know whether modern day smartphones have enough processing power/memory to recognize, say about 1 million classes from their real-time camera feed (30 fps) ?

(On-device inference or YOLO neural net concepts needed.)

What is the maximum number of classes it can reliably classify on a mobile device?

Some insight into figuring out computational loads/times in general would be helpful.

Comment: I can answer your very first question, a smartphone does NOT have the processing power to recognize 1M classes, at least not with any meaningful latency. For questions 2 & 3 you will have to do some testing yourself, I doubt many people have published any research/numbers on this.

Comment: Why would you want to discriminate a million classes?